# Access Denied 403 forbidden error in publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Two days ago, everything was working fine.  Now when I try to add an item from my web part it is giving a 403 forbidden access denied error.

Also, I am using run with elevated privileges to insert records.  It was working.
Now I can manually add items, but from my web part it is not working.  Also, I am not able to edit publishing pages.

Comment: you have permission issue . What is the error in visual sudio debugger?

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_SecurableObjectImpl()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.get_HasUniqueRoleAssignments()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAccessRequestsUtility.TryGetAccessRequestListCore(SPWeb web, SPList& arl, Boolean ignoreRoleAssignments, Boolean& incompatibleListWithSameNameExists)    
 )

Comment: this kinda error is coming and i cant debug error coming in production server

Comment: Try log some informations, how can be denied if you are using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilege`